# How to use ZF2 navigation twig partial

Tags: navigation, zend-framework2, twig, partial

I have layout.twig file with this line:

```
{{ navigation('navigation').menu().setUlClass("nav navbar-nav").setPartial(['partials/navigation.twig', 'Application'])|raw }}
```

inside of the navigation.twig I have these lines:

```
{{ ulClass }}
<?php echo "test"; die();?>
```

Unfortunately I see this as result:

```
{{ ulClass }}
test
```

Which means that twig file was parsed by default PHP render. How should I fix it? Please note layout.twig works just fine.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to override invokables in the helper_manager section:

```
    'helper_manager' => array(
        'configs' => array(
            'Zend\Navigation\View\HelperConfig'
        ),
        'invokables' => array(
            "partial" => 'Zend\View\Helper\Partial',
            "paginationControl" => 'Zend\View\Helper\PaginationControl',
        )
    )
```

After that partials are being parsed as twig files, not php.